# How to keep name and score together when sorting

Tags: python

My assignment is to take some names and scores, rank them from highest to lowest, then output the names and scores from highest to lowest. (There's some other stuff in there but this is the part that's tripping me up)

The output should look like this:

```
Jake 53

Mary 45

Tim 32

Joe 15
```

I know how to sort the scores, but I can't figure out how to make sure the names and scores stay together.

Comment: Can you give an example of your input?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `key` parameter in function `sorted`.
If you have a list of tuples ('name', score) you use something like that:

```
A = [('Tim', 32), ('Mary', 45), ('Jake', 53), ('Joe', 15)]
B = sorted(A, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
# B: [('Jake', 53), ('Mary', 45), ('Tim', 32), ('Joe', 15)]
for pair in B:
    print(pair[0], pair[1])
```

If you don't know what `lambda` is, read about it [there](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions).